# Pyramid. Changing the Not Found View for url_scheme https

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons

I use a pyramid framework, and my site working in https scheme.

I changed Not Found View - it working fine, and user sees my_fine_404 page.

But when user loads http://example.com page (not https) - user sees 404 default page (not my_fine_404).

How to change Not Found View for http scheme, if my site working in https scheme?

Some code:

Changing the Not Found View in view.py:

```
@notfound_view_config(renderer='mysite:templates/my_fine_404.pt')
def not_found(request):
    request.response.status = 404
    return {'content': u'Sorry, page not found.'}
```

Settings in *.ini for https:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = %(http_port)s
url_scheme = https
```

Comment: Do you have a "front-end" server (Apache or Nginx) which listens on port 443 and proxies to your application listening on port 80? Can you show its configuration?

Comment: Yes, I have Nginx.<br/>
I understand! I need config Nginx! Thanx!<br/>
My config:
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  example.com;
I need to to like this:
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  example.com;
yes?